# Spotify statusCode: 403,reasonPhrase: "Forbidden", User not registered in the Developer Dashboard

Tags: flutter, api, spotify, spotify-app

i am trying to access user top Spotify artist using api url

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists?limit=6&offset=5
```

but it give reponse **User not registered in the Developer Dashboard**

Even i also add   user name and email Under Users and Access  you can see here [image: user and access] in Spotify app in developer console .

Comment: how do you receive the token for the user?

Comment: hey Ashutosh did you fix this?